# Getting a "failed to merge dex" error on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, merge, dex

I am a student and am stuck. I am getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ChangedThisforPrivacy"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1"
}
```

I have tried a Clean and then Build, and the issue remains.

Comment: Did you try Clean and then Build and to be on safe side remove `enter code here`

Comment: @knitesh,  Yes i have, issue is still there.

Comment: Check you don't have any duplicated libraries

Comment: @Chisko I'm unsure how to check the libraries for duplicates if I'm going to be honest.

Comment: Check the `libs` folder for duplicate jars. If it doesn't work, look for `Invalidate caches / restart` on the File menu

Comment: (Pro tip: we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.)

Comment: (As per @Knitesh's request, you'd left a `enter code here` placeholder in your code. If people make requests for an edit, it's worth making that promptly, to make it readable for readers, and to ward off potential downvotes. I've removed it on this occasion.)